# PHP server cache (X-cache) problems

Tags: php

Lately my PHP server (paid host at [One.com](http://one.com)) has been having a huge delay (approx. 15 minutes) from I change something in my code, to the actual change in the files. When I log in to the FTP, the changes are there, but there is a 15-minutes delay to the change appears in the HTTP. This makes it completely impossible to code anything, as coding often is tweaking one little number until it's perfect. To make it short: I can't wait 15 minutes.

My host says, that it's the X-cache.

Do you know anything I (or my host) can do to solve this?

My host offered me to disable the X-cache, but they said, that there'd be a up to 30 minutes delay from entering the site, to your computer receives the HTML, as the server would have to "dig everything up from root".

Please help me!

Comment: Develop on your local workstation?

Comment: @MichaelHampton That'd work I guess, if I had one. I'm on a laptop, so I can't host a PHP server myself.

Comment: Sure you can. Unless it's something ancient from the 1990s...

Comment: @MichaelHampton Next problem is, that I'm not the only programmer working, and we're not always working at the same time, and on the same network, how would I solve that?

Comment: You use a source repository, like everyone else. Try github.

Comment: We need to have the code running live, as often we work at different files that is dependent of each other, this's slow down our coding progress. What we need is a way to develop live without delay.

Comment: Developing directly on a production system is **never** the way to go. Get a test server/site setup ASAP.

Comment: You misunderstand, we're not developing directly on our server. That'd be stupid. We're developing on our test server, but we're having this delay problems.

Comment: Also the "problem" you describe with X-cache is in fact its intended function.

Comment: Host the test site somewhere that isn't overly aggressive with caching? Get some Ops in your DevOps and bring the hosting in-house.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Like where? I'm willing to change host if necessary.

Comment: There's thousands of hosts out there. And thousands of competent sysadmins. Go shopping. :)

Comment: @MichaelHampton I just don't want any cache problems, like I have with Onecom. Despite the caching problems I'm really happy with them, cheap and good support.

Comment: If you want an Ops perspective on this, since it's getting way too long for comments, feel free to join us in [Server Fault's chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127/the-comms-room).